# Array job gives error in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

As I want to run several simulations with different values in R, I have been recommended to use a job array in bash.
1) I generated the combination of parameters and saved it in a txt file, called parameters.txt.
2) I want now to use each combination of parameters into R. Each combination is represented by a line of 3 numbers (the 3 parameters) in parameters.txt.

When I run my script, an error message appears :

> head: parameters.txt: invalid number of lines
>
> head: parameters.txt: invalid number of lines
>
> head: parameters.txt: invalid number of lines
>
> Job array item : rx=, ry=, rz=

Here is my script:

```
# Sweeping parameters.txt
N=${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}
rx=`head -n ${N} parameters.txt | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1`
ry=`head -n ${N} parameters.txt | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f2`
rz=`head -n ${N} parameters.txt | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f3`

# Display
echo "Job array item $N: rx=$rx, ry=$ry, rz=$rz"
echo "---------------------------------"

# Run
R CMD BATCH ex.R $rx $ry $rz
```

Comment: It looks like your variable `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` is not getting set.

Comment: Thanks, it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` is `None (not set)` and as a result `N` is `None` here:

```
N=${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}
```

Then bash translates it as

```
rx=`head -n parameters.txt ...
```

You can wrap with `if` statement as follows:

```
N=${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}
if [ -n "${N}" ]; then
    rx=`head -n ${N} parameters.txt | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1`
    ry=`head -n ${N} parameters.txt | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f2`
    rz=`head -n ${N} parameters.txt | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f3`

    # Display
    echo "Job array item $N: rx=$rx, ry=$ry, rz=$rz"
    echo "---------------------------------"

    # Run
    R CMD BATCH ex.R $rx $ry $rz
else
    echo "SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID / N is None"
fi
```